# do I need to define all fields in a class constructor in java?

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

for a class in java, do I need to assign values to each of the fields in the constructor?

```
public class GenericList<T> {

private final int MAX_SIZE;
private List<T> s = new ArrayList<T>();

public GenericList() {
    this.MAX_SIZE = 100;
}
```

also, in a subclass, if I want to redefine just one of the values from the superclass constructor, do I need to re-state the value from the superclass, or can I just leave it out altogether?

```
public class SafeZone extends GenericList<SafeZone> {

final private int MAX_SIZE;
private GenericList<SafeZone> safeZone;

public SafeZone() {
    super(1);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you test it out? Or read the spec?

Answer (score -1):

for a class in java it is not mandatory to assign values to each of the fields, in fact, there are constructors that can be empty and the fields can start in null.

Now, with respect to the subclass, it is not necessary to redefine the values of the superclass.